# Where is the main() method in the PHP interpreter source?

Tags: php, c

When I read the [PHP source code written in C](https://github.com/php/php-src), I can't find the `main()` method; could somebody help me?

Comment: @Let'sCode: I believe he's speaking of the source code to the PHP interpreter.

Comment: have you tried downloading the source code and using `grep(1)` against it?, perhaps `grep -i 'main[[:space:]]*(' $(find -iname '*.c')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `main()` functions in PHP are defined within the SAPI, as they are specific to the mode that PHP is being run in. For instance, for the command-line SAPI, it is defined in [`sapi/cli/php_cli.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cli/php_cli.c#L1198); for the CGI/FastCGI SAPI, it is defined in [`sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c#L1729).

Some other SAPIs, such as the `apache2` SAPI, do not define a `main()` function at all, because they are only loaded as a module by a separate executable.

Comment: Thank you very much,that's what i want

Answer (score -5):

PHP has no `main` method like C does.

PHP is executed top-to-bottom or can be called from HTML by using methods.

```
<?php
echo "echo"
echo "echo 2"
?>
```

The PHP will be run from the opening tag down to the closing tag.

Echoing `echo` and `echo 2` in order.